# Find the area of the region which is the union of three circles

Tags: geometry

How do I calculate the area of the region that is the union of the three circles shown below (each has radius $r=1$)?

[image]

Comment: ...what in the world is a squer?

Comment: What do you mean by `squer`? Are you talking about *area*?

Comment: Wild guess: The area of the union.

Answer (score 5):

Add line segments to the effect that four equilateral triangles appear in the two overlapping areas. Then the total area is then seen to  consist of (from left to right)

- two thirds of a unit disk
- two equilateral triangles
- two sixths of a unit disk
- two triangles again
- two thirds of a unit disk again

Answer (score 3):

By symmetry, you only need to consider the "upper right" quadrant:

[image]

The area of the green semicircle is $A_1={\pi\over 2}$.

The area of the red part can be computed with an integration in polar coordinates. Just realize the circle on the right is given by $r=2\cos\theta$ while the middle circle is given by $r=1$. Thus, the first quadrant intersection occurs at $\theta=\pi/3$. Then the area of the red region is just the area between these two polar curves:
$$
A_2=\int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} {1\over 2}\left[1^2-(2\cos\theta)^2\right]d\theta={\sqrt{3}\over 4}-{\pi\over 12}.
$$

Finally, by symmetry, the total area is $A=4(A_1+A_2)=\sqrt{3}+{5\pi\over 3}$.

---

Recognizing the symmetries, you could also notice that the total desired area is just the area of two circles of radius 1 plus 4 times the area of the red region (obtained by integration above),  which yields the same answer above.

Answer (score 2):

The hardest part is figure out the area of the intersection shown below:-

[image]

The rest is just simple additions and subtractions.

Hope you know how to find (1) the area of a sector; and the area of an equilateral triangle.

Answer (score 0):

The polar equation of the right-hand circle is
$$r = 2\cos \theta.$$
By the definition of cosine, the intersections between the right-hand circle and the central circle are at $\theta=\pm \frac \pi 3$.
So the area of each lune (the "ears" on the left and right formed by subtracting the central disk from each of the others) is
\begin{align*}
\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}\frac 1 2 (2\cos\theta)^2\,d\theta - \frac \pi 3
&=\int_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}(1+\cos(2\theta))\,d\theta-\frac \pi 3\\
&=\Bigl[\theta+\frac 1 2 \sin (2\theta)\Bigr]_{-\pi/3}^{\pi/3}-\frac \pi 3 \\
&=\frac {2\pi} 3 + \frac 1 2 \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}3\right)-\frac 1 2 \sin\left(-\frac {2\pi} 3\right)-\frac\pi 3 \\
&=\frac \pi 3+\frac{\sqrt 3} 2.
\end{align*}
So the total area is $\frac{5\pi}3+\sqrt 3$.